# "All of the above belong/s to the statement"

Tags: singular-vs-plural

The words "*all of the above*" should be treated as singular or as plural in the following context?

> "all of the above **belong/s** to the statement"

context: 
I wrote a question with 4 options: 
All of the following people belong to the Greek medical period except for: 
a) Hypocrites
b) Aristotle 
c) Galenus
d) all of the above belong to the statement

Comment: You misspelled "Hippocrates". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hippocrates

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually, in multiple-choice questions,

> all of the above

is used alone, without anything following it. This means that every selection above it in the list *satisfies what the question demands* (in your case, which one in the list was **not** from the Greek medical period)

I have never encountered a native speaker that used

> belong(s) to the statement

ever, period.

Here's a better version of your question:

> All of the following people belong to the Greek medical period except for:
>
> - Hippocrates
> - Aristotle
> - Galen
> - All of the above are from the Greek medical period.

This keeps the spirit of your choice of how to phrase the last option.

Answer (score -2):

"All" is plural. Therefore:

> All of the above *belong*

Comment: All of my heart belong to you? All is not always plural.

Comment: "All your base are belong to us", ColleenV?

Comment: That is an error from a shoddy translation form Japanese. The "belong" there is kind of fossilized due to its memetic status.

Comment: We do say *All of the people **are** here*, but we also say *All of the water **is** contaminated*. It might be helpful to mention that "*all* is plural" doesn't always work as a rule.

Comment: "All of (countable)" is plural, "All of (singular uncountable)" is singular.

Comment: But how do we deal with the "all of my heart"?